# UITextField and Button as TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to add UITextField and Button as [this picture](http://cdn.pttrns.com/pttrns/1656/original/IMG_2515.PNG). I think that its position is fixed and It will scroll up when keyboard appeared. I'm wondering it's kind of tableFooterView or what else?

Comment: It will be the easiest way to implement this as UITableViewFooter customView. Nevertheless yours viewController should conform UITextFieldDelegate to know when your tableView should change its own frame.

Comment: @Neru I tried by using tableFooterView it works but it's scrollable depends on row of table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `UITextField` input accessory view.

It has nothing to do with `UITabBar` or table view, just a plain old `UIView` put on top of each and every other view.

When `UITextField` on the view becomes firstResponder, you should put it over the keyboard and vice a versa.

`UITableViewFooter` is not an option here - at least look at Facebook or Instagram, it's done differently there.

Comment: So put UITextField over TableViewCell?

Comment: @user3849461 not cell, the whole view, including `UITableView`.